# Convolutional Neural Networks - Flattening with multiple feature maps

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution, artificial-intelligence

I have a very simple question about CNNs, which I unfortunately couldn't find an explanation for.

Imagine we have a CNN, that has four filters (eg right, left, top, bottom edges) each of those outputs a 2x2 feature map for simplicity. Each of them gets flattened, so we are left with 4 4x1 feature maps. Does the fully connected input layer have 4 input nodes, where we feed the 4x1 maps, or does it have 16 input nodes, each 4 corresponding to the feature map of a certain filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second proposal is the correct one. You just flatten all features maps to a single vector.

In the example in PyTorch you can see that clearly:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#define-a-convolutional-neural-network

Here all the features are flattened so you have a matrix with dimensions `batchsize x total number of features`.